# Comments field not updating

Tags: tasks, list-item, task-list, updatelistitems, cumulative-update

I am developing a workflow. I have extended the Workflow Task content type with the Comments field using SharePoint UI. I need to set some value for this field in my code when editing the task, but it stays empty. Here's my code:

```
private void SetTaskProperties(string comment)
{
    Hashtable taskProperties;

    taskProperties = new Hashtable();
    taskProperties.Add(SPBuiltInFieldId.Completed, true);
    taskProperties.Add(SPBuiltInFieldId.TaskStatus, completed);
    taskProperties.Add(SPBuiltInFieldId.PercentComplete, 1.0);
    taskProperties.Add(SPBuiltInFieldId.Comments, comment);
    SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(this.task, taskProperties, false);
}
```

Should I be using something else than `SPBuiltInFieldId.Comments`? I am getting the same result when updating the task directly, instead of using the Hashtable in the code above.

Comment: I can't check the code but I'm sure when I did this I used the alternative method of taskProperties["Comments"] = comment;, or something similar (At home can't check). Have you tried this?

Comment: I did and it doesn't work. I tried with `SPBuiltInFieldId.Comments` and with `SPBuiltInFieldId.Comment`. Did you know that there are 3 fields in SharePoint that are named Comments? This is nuts!